# Присвоить переменной значение из таблицы mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Как присвоить переменной последнее значение из нужной колонки в таблице бд mysql с помощью php?
например таблица "танки" посл запись id-45, name-t34, чтобы т34 записывалось в переменную  $tank

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT `name` FROM `tanki` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");

$tank = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

$tank = $tank['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 name from table order by id desc
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]